# update bootstrap progressbar value to 100% beforeunload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set the bootstrap progress-bar value to 100% before the page is reloaded. I am doing this inside $(window).bind('beforeunload' , but it is not working as expected. However my attempt to change the html text of p tag is successful. Please suggest.

```
<body>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ></div>
    </div>
    <p id="pp"> something <p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-progressbar-0.8.4/bootstrap-progressbar.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.progress .progress-bar').attr('data-transitiongoal', 80).progressbar({display_text: 'fill'});

            $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
                var $pb = $('.progress .progress-bar');
                $pb.attr('data-transitiongoal', 100).progressbar({display_text: 'fill'});
                $( '#pp' ).html("Reloading...");
                //return 'yes';
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How is the page reloading? Do you have a button that triggers it?

Comment: page is reloading via browser refresh button

Comment: i found this to be working for me.  $('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%').attr('aria-valuenow', 100);

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be working for me.

```
$('.pro$('.progress-bar').css('width', '100%').attr('aria-valuenow', 100);
```